# Custom search based on multiple dropdon lists

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have theese three dropdown lists filled with values:

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
<p>Width</p>
<select class="form-control" name="width">
<option value="" selected="selected">Any width</option>
<option value="135">135</option>
<option value="145">145</option>
<option value="155">155</option>
<option value="165">165</option>
<option value="175">175</option>
</select>

<p>Height</p>
<select class="form-control" name="height">
<option value="" selected="selected">Any height</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="35">35</option>
<option value="40">40</option>
<option value="45">45</option>
</select>

<p>Diameter</p>
<select class="form-control" name="diameter">
<option value="" selected="selected">Any diameter</option>
<option value="10">R10</option>
<option value="12">R12</option>
<option value="13">R13</option>
<option value="14">R14</option>
<option value="15">R15</option>
</select>

<input name="search" type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

What i try to achieve is to redirect the user to a custom url ( like example.com/tires/size-185-65-15 ) and there make the actual query and display the results.

Not the query is the real problem, but the redirection based on their choices.

The redirection should be based on the values they select from width, height and diameter ( mandatory all 3 values togheter).

Is there any way to achive this thing? I think maybe at javascript or jquery?

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Make an effort to solve the problem. If you run into a specific issue doing so, post a question with your attempt (including all the relevant code), saying what isn't working, and explaining your research so far.

Comment: hahaha, member for 6 years and still asking a question like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an id to all of your "Select" tags and then use Javascript to get their values, build a custom url and redirect to it.

```
<script>
    function submitQuery() {
        var width = document.getElementById("width").value;
        var height = document.getElementById("height").value;
        var diameter = document.getElementById("diameter").value;
        var url = "example.com/tires/size-" + width + "-" + height + "-" + diameter;
        window.location = url;
    }
</script>
<form action="search.php" method="post">
    <p>Width</p>
    <select class="form-control" name="width" id="width">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Any width</option>
        <option value="135">135</option>
        <option value="145">145</option>
        <option value="155">155</option>
        <option value="165">165</option>
        <option value="175">175</option>
    </select>

    <p>Height</p>
    <select class="form-control" name="height" id="height">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Any height</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="35">35</option>
        <option value="40">40</option>
        <option value="45">45</option>
    </select>

    <p>Diameter</p>
    <select class="form-control" name="diameter" id="diameter">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Any diameter</option>
        <option value="10">R10</option>
        <option value="12">R12</option>
        <option value="13">R13</option>
        <option value="14">R14</option>
        <option value="15">R15</option>
    </select>

    <input name="search" onclick="submitQuery()" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: this is great! but is there any way to check if all of them are selected and make the redirection only if all of them are selected?

Comment: Sure just add a condition on top, if (width != 0 && height != 0 && diameter != 0)

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:
1) Change the submit button to a link and give it an id:

```
<a href="" id="submitLink">Search</a>
```

2) Make a Javascript function that constructs the link:

```
function constructLink() {
  var link = "example.com/tires/size-";
  link += document.getElementsByName("width")[0].value;
  link += "-" + document.getElementsByName("height")[0].value;
  link += "-" + document.getElementsByName("diameter")[0].value;
  document.getElementById("submitLink").href = link;
}
```

3) Add this JS function to the change event of all three select boxes:

```
<select class="form-control" name="width" onchange="constructLink();">
```

That should be it!

Comment: It should be: `getElementsByName("width")[0]` since theoretically there can be more than one element with the same name (and the method has the plural form in its name).